# Possible Tetration extension for a specific interval (part 1)

Tags: extension-field, exponentiation, tetration, hyperoperation

My friend and I have been developing an extension of tetration for non integer values.
We managed to get definitions of extensions for : ${^r}x$.

1. $x$>0.
2. $r$ not equal to any whole number below -1.
   Here, I will only present the extention for values of x belonging to the interval $I$ = $]1,e^{1/e}[$ and $I' = [e^{-e}, 1[$

So, we know that ${^\infty}x$ here converges to a value we will call $\tau$ (for example, ${^\infty}({\sqrt2}) = 2$). Thus, we can notice that for any value of x belonging in the interval $I$,
$$\lim_{r\rightarrow{+}\infty}(\frac{{^{r+1}}x-\tau}{{^r}x-\tau})=ln(\tau)$$

$$\text{Let's call "}\ln(\tau)\text{"} \lambda$$

I haven't demonstrated that yet, but I think it wouldn't be too hard to do.
$$({^{23}}\sqrt2-2)/({^{22}}\sqrt2-2)=0.6931203376$$

(which is pretty close to ln(2) which is 0.6931471806)

This was just an example, and you can try for different values of x, it always works.
So, we can drive the formula

$$\lim_{r\rightarrow{+}\infty}({^{r+1}}x)=(({^r}x-\tau)*\lambda) +\tau$$
So we can also deduce :

$$\lim_{r\rightarrow{+}\infty}({^{r+k}}x)=(({^r}x-\tau)*\lambda^k) +\tau$$
And since tetration can be expressed recursively (meaning taking n times the $\log_x({^r}x)={^{r-n}}x$, and that we defined ${^{r+k}}x$ for any value of k (including non integer values), we can drive our final formula :

$${^r}x =(\lim_{n\rightarrow{+}\infty}(\log_{x} ^{n-k}((({^n}x-\tau)*\lambda^p) +\tau))$$

Where $k+p=r$, $k$ being an integer and $|p|<1$, and $\log_x^n$ means taking n times the log (or iterating n times the log).

With this formula, we can define ${^r}x$ for values of r lower than -2, BUT NOT whole negatives below or equal to minus 2. For example, $r=-1$ is ok, same for $r=-3.64, r=-15.9$, but $r=-2,r=-3,r=-4$, ... is forbidden.

The formula looks hard but is really easy to understand, for example, to calculate ${^{0.5}}(\sqrt2)$, we take a big value of ${^n}(\sqrt2)$ (like $n=23$), we substract $2$, multiply by $\ln(2)^{0.5}$, we add $2$, and take the $\log_{\sqrt2}$ $n$ times ($23$ times here). And we get a good approximation.

With this formula, I have the following results :

${^{-0.5}}({\sqrt2})≈0.6290566121$.
${^{1.3}}({\sqrt2})≈1.49334127$.
${^{-{\sqrt2}}}({\sqrt2})≈-1$.
${^{-{2.5}}}({\sqrt2})≈0.8390270267+9.064720284i$
etc...

Here is the graph of ${^{x}}({\sqrt2})$ from -2 to 4.

[image: here is the graph of ${^x}(\sqrt2)]

(It seems like this function is symmetrical, meaning ${^x}(\sqrt2)=a\leftrightarrow{^{-a}}(\sqrt2)=-x$)

ASLO, this formula can be applied for numbers x belonging to the internal $I' = [e^{-e}, 1[$. The main difference here, is that $\lambda$ is negative, implying that real non integer tetration gives complex results.
For example, here are some values of ${^x}0.5$ :

${^{0.5}}0.5 ≈ 0.6297281585+0.2178921319i$.
${^{-1.9}}0.5 ≈ 2.487456488+1.718168223i$.
etc...

Here is the graph of ${^x}0.5~$ from -2 to 5. (red is the real part, blue is the imaginary part)

[image]

For ${^r}1$, I think it makes sense to define it as being equal to $1$ for at least all r belonging to $]-1,+\infty[$.

Anyway, tell me what you think of this. Do you think this extension is correct? Plausible? Or bad?

EDIT : apparently my conjecture about ${^r}(\sqrt2)$ being symmetrical is false.

Comment: Short comment on the "symmetry": I've no concrete data, but someone in the tetration forum mentioned that he had found out that there is no symmetry, but can only be seen with higher numerical precision in the computation. (Perhaps it cannot be seen with computations using Desmos)

Comment: Found the reference: *"We graph the two corresponding different half-iterates of $h(z)=\sqrt 2 \,^z $. An apparent symmetry of the tetrational to base $\sqrt 2 $ disproved."* 

$\text{MATHEMATICS OF COMPUTATION} \\
\text{Volume 79, Number 271, July 2010, Pages 1727–1756 }\\
\text{S 0025-5718(10)02342-2 }\\
\text{Article electronically published on February 12, 2010 }\\
\text{PORTRAIT  OF  THE  FOUR  REGULAR  SUPER-EXPONENTIALS TO  BASE  SQRT(2) }\\
\text{DMITRII KOUZNETSOV AND HENRYK TRAPPMANN } $ (available via ref-database at tetrationforum)

Comment: Hmm, I don't know, I get different values for your base $b=0.5$. $$\small \begin{array} {}
h=0.5 &0.6297281585   + 0.2178921319  î &Carlier\;Q\;MSE \\
h=0.5 &0.629789099994 + 0.217867330431 î&Carlier (r=10)\\
h=0.5   &0.629786228396 + 0.217861863125 î &Carlier (r=50)\\
h=0.5    &0.629786228396 + 0.217861863125 î&Schröder \\
\hline 
h=-1.9 &2.487456488   + 1.718168223   î&Carlier\;Q\;MSE\\
h=-1.9 &2.48780504335 + 1.71779907386 î&Carlier (r=10)\\
h=-1.9  &2.48770151179 + 1.71816678986 î&Carlier (r=50)\\
h=-1.9  &2.48770151179 + 1.71816678986 î&Schröder \\
\end{array}
$$

Comment: Just for sanity-check: my parameters: fixpoint: $\tau \approx 0.641185744505$ log of fixpoint: $\lambda \approx -0.444436091019 $. Internal computation precision in Pari/GP: 200 dec digits (my standard/default)

Comment: Hmm, differences of the same order (only 4 digits equal) are also with your earlier posted values. I've tried with some common errors, but no way could reproduce your values.

Comment: Remember my values are pretty approximative, I'm not using a very powerful calculator. I'm working with my friend to make a online calculator which is more precise. Don't take my values as the real values, but as rough 2 digit approximations.

Comment: I see - good luck with your online calculator!

Comment: I used $r=20$, not that precise.

Comment: If things are not precise, perhaps already the $\tau$-value gives differences? And then the root of $\lambda$ being a complex value... (you might notice that even using $r=10$ the values at my calculations came out nearer to the highprecise calculations, so $r=20$ being farer away must have a different/an additional reason)

Comment: No, it's probably my calculator, since I calculated it thanks to mi TI-83 PREMIUM (Texas instrument)

Comment: I think the main advantage of my method, is that it's easy to understand, easy to compute and is pretty coherent theoretically and in practice. I will post my two ther sub methods soon so stay up to tell me what you think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good idea! As far as I see, this might be seen as a "light" version of the method which has been invented by Ernst Schröder.

To make this a bit better visible let me simplify your notation and then compare your with Schröder's formula.
The value $\,^\infty x$ is a fixpoint; let's denote it as $\tau$, then let us denote its logarithm with $\lambda$.

Then your formula $\lim_{r\rightarrow{+}\infty}({^{r+k}}x)=(({^r}x-V_r)*\ln(V_r)^k) +V_r$ can be written as
$$ \lim_{r\rightarrow{+}\infty}{^{r+k}}x = (({^r}x-\tau) \cdot \lambda^k + \tau \tag 1
$$
Schröder has a version of this with some function
$$\sigma(z)=1 \cdot z+b_2 z^2 + b_3 z^3 +... \tag {2a}$$ and the inverse function $$\sigma^{\circ-1}(z)=1 \cdot z+c_2 z^2 + c_3 z^3 +\cdots \qquad \text{ . }\tag {2b}$$

First he computes $$ w=\sigma(x-\tau) \tag {3a}$$ -which might roughly be seen as your initial expression $ {^r}x-\tau$  and inserts this into $\sigma^{\circ -1}()$  as
$$ v = \sigma^{\circ -1}(w \cdot \lambda^k) \tag {3b}$$
which is more explicite
$$ v= (w \lambda^k) + c_2 (w \lambda^k)^2 + c_3 (w \lambda^k)^3 + ... \tag {3c}$$
and gets then
$$ {^k}x = v+\tau \tag 4 $$

Because the powerseries $\sigma()$ and $\sigma^{\circ -1}()$ have a small range of convergence it is better, like you do it, to use $r$'th iterates towards the fixpoint
$$ w_r=\sigma( {^r}x-\tau) \\ 
  v_r=\sigma^{\circ -1}( w_r \cdot \lambda^k ) \tag {5a} $$
and then
$$
 {^k}x= {^{-r}} \left( v_r  + \tau \right) \tag {5b} 
$$

It becomes visible now, how your idea gives an approximation to the Schröder-mechanism, because by (eq 3c) one can see that your version just uses the linear term. This can be defended: because if we use $w_r$ with large $r$ then $w_r$ is small, and the second and all further terms vanish when $w_r$ vanishes.

---

There is one important note to be appended with the use of fixpoints and shifting to fixpoints: for instance base $\sqrt 2$ has **two** fixpoints, not only $\tau_1=2$ but as well $\tau_2=4$ (and moreover infinitely many complex fixpoints). Which fixpoint do you use? Schröder requires you use the "attracting" fixpoint (if there is one), but the "repelling" one can be operated if we do not use the exponentiation $ {^k}x$ but the logarithmizing
$ {^{-k}}x$ and insert $\tau_2 (=4)$ in the formulae.
This looks totally compatible - but it isn't! [We get different values for the fractional iterates](https://math.eretrandre.org/tetrationforum/showthread.php?tid=319&pid=3570#pid3570).
I think it is important to be aware of this incompatibility over fixpoints.

---

One more general remark: I think it is always meaningful to recall that any found *(or let it as well be "any intended")* method plays in a garden of various methods and there is not yet consensus, which is "the best". To get a feeling for this I recommend to [look at a small treatize](https://go.helms-net.de/math/tetdocs/ComparisionOfInterpolations.pdf) where I compare 5 methods visually, and show the differences in the complex plane. The method you found here is very close to that which I invented there, only that this simple method was based on linearization of the log-polar expression of the iterates ${^r}x-\tau$ near the fixpoint: its there with the label "poor man's Schröder implementation". Have fun!

Comment: Just checked numerically: the linear logpolar interpolation ("poor man's...") seems to be exactly the interpolation as proposed in the OP ...

Comment: well thanks for your comment. So technically my method approximates another method for tetration, is that right? If so, then it should converge to the same values. Also, if it was possible to mathematically demonstrate that formula, would it make it more credible as potentially the "best" tetration extension method? Also, this method can be applied for numbers belonging to $[e^{-e},1[$, the only difference is that it gives complex values for real positive non integer hights. I also have 2 other methods for other intervals, so I'm going to do some updates, stay tuned if you're interested!

Comment: @PierreCarlier - *"So technically my method approximates another method for tetration, is that right? If so, then it should converge to the same values. "* Yes to both. *"...make it the best..."* don't think it is possible from the mathematical model alone. Remember the early discussion about the interpolation of the factorial. Nobody knew, what is "the best" method. Euler's method was later accepted as "the best method" - but because of some specific properties. For tetration you might involve in the discussion about "uniqueness". I've not yet done "my choice" ;-) ...

Comment: Well first I'll present the 3 sub-methods my friend and I developed. Here there's only 1 which I presented. For me, this is the best one. There's another one which is less convincing, and one which I'm really not sure about

Comment: Btw, could we define 1 tetration z as being 1 for all z? (even complex, and - 2,-3,-4,... Values?

Comment: @PierreCarlier - sorry, I'm not so expert to be able for a qualified answer to this. However I've found the existence of (countably) infinitely many *periodic points* (at least in the right halfplane of complex numbers). The idea, that we could connect the, say three, members of a set of periodicity 3 with continuous trajectories, cannot be done: because they cannot be periodic continuous trajectories - otherwise we had not only countably periodic points but uncountably infinitely many periodic points. So there are infinitely many points where your one method cannot be applied. (...)

Comment: (...) This is not proved, but seems to me a meaningful/ necessary consequence of the *"countable infinititude"* of periodic points. (See my question in MO https://mathoverflow.net/q/391772/7710 Mar 2021 with more details)

Comment: (...) Another link, going to the tetration forum where I discussed this problem as well : https://math.eretrandre.org/tetrationforum/showthread.php?tid=1277

Comment: @PierreCarlier - upps, may be I misread your "... define 1 tetration z as being..." as meaning "... is there *one method* of tetration valid for all numbers ..." This might have been a total misreading. If so, I beg pardon!

Comment: Yeah you misread that but that's ok. But I guess there's at least one method that could be defined at least for positive values of x and real values of r not equal to any whole number below -1

Comment: Btw what's the method you've created to extend tetration?

Comment: @PierreCarlier - ehhmm: "extend"? What do you mean with that?

Comment: Well defining it for non integer values of the height.

Comment: I know two methods down to programming details: Schröder-method (including the "light weight" Schröder or "poor man's" ) , the Walker-method (not yet much practice though), the Walker/Robbins-method and the "polynomial method" based on truncated Carlemanmatrices. They are well defined for at least one unit of height, they are -for instance- not entire for the starting values of $z_0$ and I don't know always the range of convergence for the $z$-argument. Not much knowledge about the (real or even complex) range for bases $b$.

Comment: Where can you find the details about these methods online?

Comment: No compilation of implementations or indepth math description so far. You must collect the pieces from everywhere, and a framework to generalize this from specific parameters etc is not even thought of. The best resource is surely the tetrationforum, there is discussion (much unstructured) and a handful of text attached, for instance Trappmann/Kouznetzows "5+methods" which is also linked to above in the comments. A very basic introduction of my matrixmethods is in https://go.helms-net.de/math/tetdocs/ContinuousfunctionalIteration.pdf but it is introductory for the level (...)

Comment: (...) for the level at which was myself when I wrote this ;-) Various material, even the actual computation of the diagonalization for triangular Carleman-matrices, can you find when you scan my directory of tet-docs: https://go.helms-net.de/math/tetdocs/ .Sorry cannot provide a link to something like "numerical recipes" with c++-sources...

Comment: I posted part 2 of my method. You can check out if you're interested